# Code coverage on IDE is not the same as code coverage on website

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

When I run my junit tests on Eclipse, I get a pretty high percentage. However, when I run in through my school's online assignment turn-in page, it gets an extremely low code coverage. I believe that this has something to do with the following code:

```
CompetitionDijkstra (String filename, int sA, int sB, int sC){

    Scanner x;


   this.sA = sA;
   this.sB = sB;
   this.sC = sC;

   try {
       x = new Scanner(new File(filename));
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
       x = null;
       System.out.println("could not find file");
   }

   String v_str = x.next();
   String e_str = x.next();
   this.v = Integer.parseInt(v_str);
   this.e = Integer.parseInt(e_str);

   this.graph = new EdgeWeightedGraph(v);
   Edge buff = new Edge(0, 0, 0);

   String bv_str;
   String bw_str;
   String bweight_str;

   int bv, bw;
   double bweight;

   while(x.hasNext()) {
       bv_str = x.next();
       bw_str = x.next();
       bweight_str = x.next();

       bv = Integer.parseInt(bv_str);
       bw = Integer.parseInt(bw_str);
       bweight = Double.parseDouble(bweight_str);

       buff = new Edge(bv, bw, bweight);

       this.graph.addEdge(buff);
   }


   x.close();
}
```

Specifically the line `String v_str = x.next();`

The website is telling me that it is getting a java.lang.NullPointerException from this line, despite me not getting any errors or warnings on the IDE. I suspect that it might have to do with having a try-catch inside the constructor, but I can't be sure.

Is there anything wrong with the code? I would like to be sure before I ask my professors any questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the scanning on the website? I mean Does it read from the Stdin, File,..etc?

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is on topic for stackoverflow. Stackoverflow isn't a code proof reading service.

Comment: @am0awad That information isn't available to me, I'm afraid.

Comment: Try to read from Stdin: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: @am0awad Thank you for your reply. However, I've tried this and it does not work. In fact, the website says that nothing is read. I'm not sure what the source of the problem is, considering Eclipse says that the tests cover most of the code.

Comment: @iaskdumbstuff Well, look at what happens if an exception is thrown with the `x = new Scanner(new File(filename))` statement. The `catch` block is entered and `x` is set to `null`. But then the execution continues below the `catch` block, `x.next()` is called while `x` is `null`. That causes an NPE to be thrown.